# Arquillian Persistence Extension - Long execution time, is it normal?

Tags: persistence, jboss-arquillian

I'm writing some tests with arquillian for persistence layer in my app. I would like to use an Persistence Extension for database populating etc. The problem is that one test takes about ~15-25 seconds. Is it normal? Or am I doing something wrong? I've tried to run these tests on local postgres database (~10sec per test), remote postgres database (~15sec per test) and hsqldb at local container (~15sec per test).

Thanks in advance

P.S. When I'm not using "Persistence Extension" 12 tests takes about ~11sec (and that's acceptable), but I have to persist and delete entities from the code (hard to maintain and manage).

Comment: Your tests are executing in a transaction.  Pretty much all containers and databases have extra over head for inserting over the transaction.  That's probably the extra time delay you're seeing.  How much data are you inserting?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you are using APE (Arquillian Persistence Extension) v1.0.0a6. If this is the case what you are experiencing is the result of refactoring done between alpha5 and alpha6 which I filed the following ticket against: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1440

You could try using 1.0.0a5 which has some different issues that you might encounter and need to work around but it has 300% better performance then alpha6.